# Oracle connection pooling takes a lot of time for first call

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-mvc, odbc

In spring I have a datasource defined in this way:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close"> 
    <property name="URL" value="${jdbc.url}" /> 
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"/> 
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/> 
    <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/> 
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

This datasource is used by my REST service and everything works fine...anyway first REST call is very slow (about ~5 secs), after that EVERY other call is fast.

I think this is an initialization related problem, in the sense that initialization is made when first DB call is received.
Is there a way to tell spring to initialize this datasource on server startup?

Answer (score 1):

> I think this is an initialization related problem, in the sense that
>   initialization is made when first DB call is received.

With your current config I think that's what's happening.

> Is there a way to tell spring to initialize this datasource on server
>   startup?

It's the behavior of the connection pool, not Spring.  Spring is  creating the bean when your app starts (you aren't using `lazy-init="true"` on the bean).  However, the connection pool isn't creating connections to the database when Spring instantiates it.  From the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/e10788/optimize.htm#CFHCHHDE):

> The initial pool size property specifies the number of available
>   connections that are created when the connection pool is initially
>   created or re-initialized. This property is typically used to reduce
>   the ramp-up time incurred by priming the pool to its optimal size.
>
> A value of 0 indicates that no connections are pre-created. The
>   default value is 0.

Try setting a non-zero value for `initialPoolSize`.

**Edit**: Try setting [ConnectionCacheProperties](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html#setConnectionCacheProperties_java_util_Properties_) instead:

```
<property name="connectionCacheProperties">
    <props merge="default">
        <prop key="InitialLimit">5</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```